# How to intercept class creation and add attribute using a metaclass?

Tags: python

In the following code, I want metaclass `NameMeta` to add attribute `gender` to `MyName` class in case this class does not declare that attribute.

```
class NameMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        if 'gender' not in dic:
            setattr(name, 'gender', 'Male')
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dic)

class MyName(metaclass=NameMeta):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname       
    def fullname(self):
        self.full_name = self.fname + self.lname
        return self.full_name 
inst = MyName('Joseph ', 'Vincent')
print(MyName.gender)
```

This is the output that I am getting:

```
<ipython-input-111-550ff3cfae41> in __new__(cls, name, bases, dic)
      2     def __new__(cls, name, bases, dic):
      3         if 'gender' not in dic:
----> 4             setattr(name, 'gender', 'Male')
      5         return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dic)
      6 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'gender'
```

I know this error makes sense since `name` is a string.
My question is, how can I access `MyName` class as an object in the metaclass so that I can add the attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close. Your problem is that you were trying to add your attribute to the name of the *meta-class* using `name`, which is a string. You need to assign the attribute to the class object you're creating. This can be done using `dic`:

```
class NameMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dic):
        if 'gender' not in dic:
            dic['gender'] = 'Male'
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dic)
```

With the above change your code outputs:

```
Male
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much for the quick response. I have to say that I honestly thought that cls reffered to the class it is in in this case NameMeta.

Comment: @VincentJ.Michuki I've update my answer. As Artyer so kindly pointed out, you need to use: `dic['gender'] = 'Male'`.

Comment: You could use `dic.setdefault('gender', 'Male')` instead of the "if not present then insert". Probably not faster but "shorter". :)

Comment: Well you could, but you _should you_?. `dict.setdefault` returns a value, so it'd seem to me that you'd really only be using it for it's side-effects. But yeah, it'd be shorter ;-)

Comment: Never figured out if it's a side-effect or if it was the main purpose (look at the name) and just too convenient to let that function return. It's one of the odd methods that modify and return... But I know it's avoiding hashing the value twice and you don't need a `try` and `except`. :D

Comment: @ChristianDean you are right, dic['gender'] = 'Male' is the way to go as it sets it on instances as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add it to the `dic` if it is not present, as it holds the class's attribute:

```
def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dict):
    if 'gender' not in dict:
        dict['gender'] = 'Male'
    # or just `dict.setdefault('gender', 'Male')`
    return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dic)

    # Or you can create the class and set it

    cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dic)
    if not hasattr(cls, 'gender'):
        cls.gender = 'Male'
    return cls
```

Or you could have a class attribute:

```
class NameMeta(type):
    gender = 'Male'
    # `gender = 'Male'` will be inherited by all classes
    # but not instances of those classes.
```